# How to do a double redirect in a single html link?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm working with codeigniter and I just wanna know How could I deconnect from a session AND from Facebook ni a single link ?

Let me explain, I got some FB info stored in some $data
I also have a session set for the user

when i press the log out button 
    user/logout()">DeconnexionFB

I call a logout function within the user controller .
Here is the function :

```
public function logout()
{
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    $fb_data=NULL;

    redirect('site','refresh');
}
```

but whar I want to dois to reach the logout url from fb in the same time to disconnect the user to his FB session, for that I need an anchor to an external URL.
How could I redirect my website automatically to that adress within the controller after deleting the $fb_data and destroying my session ?

an anchor like that :
Disconnect

thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I would add the JavaScript SDK for facebook to your site, if you already haven't, by adding:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
 window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
   appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
   channelURL : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
   status     : true, // check login status
   cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
   oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
   xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
  });
  // Additional initialization code here
 };
 // Load the SDK Asynchronously
 (function(d){
  var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
  d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
 }(document));
</script>
```

Copied from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Then in your code you would call:

```
FB.logout(function(response) {
  // user is now logged out
});
```

Copied from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/

With this you will not have to redirect to another page but call it in your logout page. But be careful some people would not like to be logged out of facebook the same time they logout of your site.